# Login user automatically after successful registration

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I have login and registration activity in my App, I want user to automatically logged in soon after successful registration. Can i insert login code just after onCompleteListener of Registration?

Comment: Firebase registration **is** a login, as the FirebaseAuth user is changed

Comment: Can i get Uid of registered user? Just as we get uid of logged in user!

Comment: Yes. `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()`

Comment: True, Basically i have login and register activity, so if user click on profile(Bottom Navigation item) If he is not logged in , He is prompted to login first if he has account, otherwise he has to register , after registration, The registration activity closes but login activity launches again, so i'm thinking that currently uid is null

Answer (score 0):

Yes!, you can get the registered user in your `OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>`.

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>, View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth

    // register button on click listener
    override fun onClick(){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password).addOnCompleteListener(this)
    }

    override fun onComplete(task: Task<AuthResult>) {
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            authUser(mAuth.currentUser)
        }
    }

    fun authUser(user: FirebaseUser?){
        // a user is returned upon successful registration
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Got problem solved, Thanks for reply, PS i'm using JAVA not Kotlin